# Plotting a clustered/stacked bar graph in r

Tags: r, bar-chart, stacked-bar-chart

I would like to plot a stacked or clustered bar graph with this data:

I used this code to melt the data into 3 columns.

```
dfm <- melt(df[,c('Depth','Site','Bailey','BR','BW','Cadet','OCN','OCS','RT','Snelling','Winter')],id.vars = 1)
```

[image]

But it is not giving me columns for site, depth, and values for sand, clay, and silt respectively. Here is what I got from the code (kindly see link or image). Please how can I tweak this code to achieve my object. Better still, please what alternative way can I follow to accomplish drawing a stacked or clustered bar graph?

Thanks.

P/S: I want to upload the file but unable to do that

Comment: Please copy and paste in your code into the question. Also add the results from `dput(df)`. This will provide a sample of your data,  the call to  `melt()` function is incorrect.  The value column is changing from numeric to character strings